Connected-component labeling in Mathematica?
I needed an implementation of the well-known one-pass connected-component labeling algorithm, see
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling
and I have programmed it myself according to the verbal description. The algorithm works as intended.
However, it came to my attention that Mathematica has many commands related to graph theory, so I suspect this well-known algorithm could be built in. However, I see only examples with directed graphs. In the problem at hand, graphs are not directed and, I confess, that I do not know the graph theory well enough.
Could anybody tell me if this algorithm is implemented in Mathematica?
For instance, I have a random matrix
NN = 30;
RM = Table[RandomInteger[], {i, 1, NN}, {j, 1, NN}];


and I interpret values 1 as islands and values 0 as the sea. Connected island is a group of one's having at least one neighbor with the value one on the left, on the right, above, or below. How to make a graph of this matrix and use Mathematica to enumerate all islands?
How do we modify the algorithm to take into account diagonal neighbors? How do we include the neighbors within a given connection range? How do we solve this problem for periodic boundary conditions? I have programmed all this but maybe Mathematica gives a quicker solution?
Addition on 23 April 2024. The discussion has shown that Mathematica's command MorphologicalComponents[], designed for images, also works on matrices. In particular, the command
Tally[Flatten[MorphologicalComponents[RM]]]

gives all labels and the numbers of positions that belong to the particular label. It turns out that this command takes into account neighbors on the left, right, top, and bottom, as well as the diagonal neighbors. I haven't found an option that controls the connection range (that I have in my implementation).

ConnectedComponents

Please take a look at MorphologicalComponents. It also has an option called CornerNeighbors. Additionaly, see ComponentMeasurements. Note that you will have to first convert your matrix into image, Image[RM].

As in MorphologicalComponents[Image@RM] // Colorize// Show[#, ImageSize -> Medium] &

Great! MorphologicalComponents[] also works on matrices and there is no need to convert them into images - see Mathematica Reference.

g = RandomGraph[{50, 40}];

h = ConnectedComponents[g];

HighlightGraph[g, h]

or
rM = Table[RandomInteger[], {i, 30}, {j, 30}];

h = AdjacencyGraph[rM];

ConnectedComponents[h]

================
(* Gosh... not even an upvote from the OP! *)

Thank you, David! Now the problem is to define a graph for a particular model, see the example I added.

Try with
RM = IncidenceMatrix@RandomGraph[{40, 20}] // Normal;
g = IncidenceGraph[RM]
